# ¿Cómo imprimir el formato ['22', '18', '16', '12'] para una lista?

Tags: java, java-17

Tengo el siguiente codigo que recibe una lista de valores como esta: 12 18 22 16 16. Es un programa que ya ordena de mayor a menor los valores y los imprime excluyendo valores repetidos osea 22, 18, 16, 12 no se toma en cuenta el segundo 16.

Mi problema es que para imprimir los valores estos se muestran asi [22, 18, 16, 12] y quiero que se muestren con el sigiente formato: ['22', '18', '16', '12'], agregando las comillas. ¿Hay alguna forma de forma de hacerlo utilizando métodos y no un for?

la entrada es: 12 18 22 16 16

la salida esperada es : ['22', '18', '16', '12']

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        List<String> edades = new ArrayList<>();
        
        edades.addAll(Arrays.asList(br.readLine().split(" ")));
        edades.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());
        edades =  edades.stream().distinct().toList();
        
        System.out.print(edades);
    }
```

Ya he intentado agregar las comillas accediendo al valor de la lista con un for pero no funciona.

Comment: Y pq quieres que salgan las comillas, no le veo sentido a lo pides, que utilidad tiene que aparezcan las comillas

Comment: Puedes hacer algo como: `lista.forEach(elemento -> "'" + elemento + "'")`. Tampoco es que existan muchas formas de hacerlo.

Comment: Puedes usar: `String edadesString = edades.toString().replaceAll("\\d+", "'$0'");` y luego simplemente `System.out.println(edadesString);`.

Comment: Por cierto to programa no está ordenando correctamente los valores de mayor a menor. Prueba algo como `12 18 22 16 9` y verás que el 9 aparece de primero incluso cuando es el menor número. El problema radica en que estás ordenando strings no integers.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios ya logré resolverlo